# Extracting data from file using multiple instances

Tags: java, javafx

The following code displays `JavaFX` charts in `Swing`. The code works perfectly fine and all my other classes work perfectly fine. For some reason, the code presents the errors:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)
    at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:451)
    at ImportCSV.ExportData(ImportCSV.java:39)
    at ImportCSV.Inportdata(ImportCSV.java:60)
    at Bar.createAndPlotBarChart(Bar.java:9)
    at ChartFrame.<init>(JavaChartDemo.java:29)
    at JavaChartDemo$1.run(JavaChartDemo.java:13)
```

When I display two charts ( `grid.add(scatter.getScatter(0),0,0);` ) it doesn't compile and run but when I add only one chart (either the bar chart or the scatter diagram), it compiles and runs perfectly fine. It just doesn't make any sense to me. The 3 commented lines cause the errors but they work fine if we uncomment them and comment the scatter chart instances. I'm guessing extracting data from the file in 2 instances is what causes this problem. Any solutions are appreciated.

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class JavaChartDemo {
    public static void main ( String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ChartFrame mainFrame = new ChartFrame();
                mainFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}

class ChartFrame extends JFrame {

    JFXPanel fxPanel;
    ScatterPlot scatter = new ScatterPlot();
    //Bar barChart = new Bar();

    public ChartFrame(){
        initSwingComponents();
        scatter.createAndPlotScatter();
        //barChart.createAndPlotBarChart();
        initFxComponents();
    }

    private void initSwingComponents(){
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        mainPanel.add(fxPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel("Charts in Swing applications");
        mainPanel.add(titleLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(mainPanel);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(800,400);
    }

    private void initFxComponents(){
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                GridPane grid = new GridPane();
                Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 800, 400);

                grid.add(scatter.getScatter(0),0,0);
                //grid.add(barChart.getBarChart(8),2,0);

                fxPanel.setScene(scene);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no way anyone can help you, you didn't provide enough information.

However the stacktrace is clear. Something happenns in the Bar class, ImportCSV is used in it, import and export (?) are happening in the import class, and you try to be convert an empty string to a number. That's what your problem is.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)
    at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:451)
    at ImportCSV.ExportData(ImportCSV.java:39)
    at ImportCSV.Inportdata(ImportCSV.java:60)
    at Bar.createAndPlotBarChart(Bar.java:9)
    at ChartFrame.<init>(JavaChartDemo.java:29)
    at JavaChartDemo$1.run(JavaChartDemo.java:13)
```

The stacktrace has really all the information you need to solve this problem.

Comment: Believe me it's none of that, but i did think the same thing initially. I've solved it. The solution was to perform data extraction once and use that instance to access the data for the different graphs/ charts etc. I would post my entire code to show that this is the first  i've come across a problem where it's LITERALLY the compiler that got it wrong due to clashes of multiple instances accessing the same file but i wouldn't as it's an assessed project. The data import/export class has no problems at all and it works now.

Comment: What do you mean the "compiler gets it wrong?". You're claiming the byte ode generated in the class file doesn't correspond to the source code in your Java file?

Comment: @James_D I can only say the stacktrace did not provide the actual faults as the code does not come across an empty string and tries to parse that as float or any of the rest mentioned errors. I did exactly what i posted as an answer (i did not modify any classes or files besides the one shown) and all the complaints vanished. I'm confused myself!

Comment: @James_D Oh, and the reason for why there never is an empty string converted to a number is because an earlier part of the program replaces all the empty strings with characters. The stacktrace referred to a line where there is never actually any empty strings (they were taken care of in the earlier parts).

Comment: The compiler isn't wrong, your code is. If you want help, post an MCVE. Or at least the ImportCSV class.

Comment: @Roland I solved it without having to look at the ImportCSV class. As you said earlier, it can only be a concurrency problem. The ImportCSV class never actually reads any empty strings.